# Identification of cocoon

Tags: botany

Looks like metal and has grown lines around it. Tried to search about it but didn't find results. Hanging on 1 of my plants. Curious to know which insect is inside. Please answe4 if anyone knows [image]

Comment: Please answer fast .....want to know

Comment: people will answer in their own time, if at all, and requesting that people hurry is not an appropriate use for comments. Improving your question will help to attract an answer. I can think of three things that will help. 1, Correct the spelling errors. 2, include the geographic details of where the cocoon is. 3, add a photo that has the cocoon in focus so that people can identify it.

Comment: Are you asking about the thing that is not in focus? Because if you are, then I suggest getting a new photo where it is. Could you add information about where you took the photo, what time of year, and what kind of plant? All of this will be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

In spite of the fuzzy picture, I think it's safe to say the chrysalis is that of the [Common Crow Butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euploea_core) in its shiny stage.

Here is a sharper picture:

[image]

The orientation of the chrysalis is about 180° from yours; however, the various bulges and markings match up, and the host plant *looks* appropriate (without identification.)

> The common crow (Euploea core) is a common butterfly found in South Asia and Australia. In India it is also sometimes referred to as the common Indian crow, and in Australia as the Australian crow. It belongs to the crows and tigers subfamily Danainae (Danaini tribe).

<sub>If you want to know how I found it, I used Google Images and searched "gold metallic colored cocoon". it was right on the first page. :)</sub>

Comment: A nice LMGTFY answer! +1

Comment: @James - Teach a man to fish, and all that.